# Prestashop cart save amount

Tags: prestashop, cart

I'm on Prestashop 1.6.0.9 and i would like to add a block : "save amount" on cart page, just below "Total".
I use specific prices and i want to show to customers how much they save money.
How can i do that ?
I think i must work with the cart-summary.js file.

```
// Block cart
$('#cart_block_shipping_cost').show();
$('#cart_block_shipping_cost').next().show();
if (json.total_shipping > 0)
{
    if (priceDisplayMethod !== 0)
    {
        $('#cart_block_shipping_cost').html(formatCurrency(json.total_shipping_tax_exc, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
        $('#cart_block_wrapping_cost').html(formatCurrency(json.total_wrapping_tax_exc, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
        $('#cart_block_total').html(formatCurrency(json.total_price_without_tax, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
    }
    else
    {
        $('#cart_block_shipping_cost').html(formatCurrency(json.total_shipping, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
        $('#cart_block_wrapping_cost').html(formatCurrency(json.total_wrapping, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
        $('#cart_block_total').html(formatCurrency(json.total_price, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
    }
}
else
{
    if (json.carrier.id == null)
    {
        $('#cart_block_shipping_cost').hide();
        $('#cart_block_shipping_cost').next().hide();
    }
}

$('#cart_block_tax_cost').html(formatCurrency(json.total_tax, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
$('.ajax_cart_quantity').html(nbrProducts);

// Cart summary
$('#summary_products_quantity').html(nbrProducts + ' ' + (nbrProducts > 1 ? txtProducts : txtProduct));
if (priceDisplayMethod !== 0)
    $('#total_product').html(formatCurrency(json.total_products, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
else
    $('#total_product').html(formatCurrency(json.total_products_wt, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
$('#total_price').html(formatCurrency(json.total_price, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
$('#total_price_without_tax').html(formatCurrency(json.total_price_without_tax, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
$('#total_tax').html(formatCurrency(json.total_tax, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
```

The problem is that i have the variable total_price (with discount) but not total_price without discount.
How can i add total_price without discount ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this topic:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/267756-display-total-discount-in-cart-summary-solved/

Especially #20:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/267756-display-total-discount-in-cart-summary-solved/#entry1348278

Author: Gowtham from prestashop.com

> Add the variable initialization around 574 in shopping-cart.js
>
> ```
> var total_disc =0;
> var price_disc =0;
> ```
>
> Add the below code around line 652 in shopping-cart.js
>
> ```
> total_disc +=(product_list[i].price_without_quantity_discount*product_list[i].quantity_without_customization
> ```
>
> - product_list[i].price*product_list[i].quantity_without_customization );
>       price_disc =((product_list[i].price_without_quantity_discount  - product_list[i].price
>   )*product_list[i].quantity_without_customization);
>       $('#price_disc_'+key_for_blockcart).html(formatCurrency(price_disc ,currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
>
> ```
> }
>
> $('#total_discount_price').html(formatCurrency(total_disc ,currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
> ```
>
> use total_discount_price as id in shopping-cart.tpl for total discount
>   and use
>
> ```
> price_disc_{$product.id_product}_{$product.id_product_attribute}{if
> ```
>
> $quantityDisplayed >
>   0}*nocustom{/if}*{$product.id_address_delivery|intval}{if
>   !empty($product.gift)}_gift{/if}
>
> as id in shopping-cart-product-line.tpl for product discount. The
>   above shown code is the representation of key_for_blockcart in js.